# Search results not appearing for scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

Lately I've been learning web scraping, with the goal of scraping some news sites. Today I first tried to scrape some search results, but, to my surprise, even though I can find them on Google Chrome's inspector, they don't appear on my BeautifulSoup object.

I tried scraping this website: https://www.latercera.com/search/?q=camila%20vallejo

I noticed the links are under the tag div, with class 'gsc-wrapper' , so I try:

```
html = urlopen('https://www.latercera.com/search/?q=camila%20vallejo')
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
bs.find('div',{'class':'gsc-wrapper'})
```

But that brings a Nonetype. After inspecting every link in my object, there's no trace of the search result links. Anyone has any idea of what could be happening?

Edit: forgot to mention, the lowest I can go in the parse tree is here:

```
bs.find('div',{'class':'searchresults'})
```

Which only brings:

```
<div class="searchresults">
<gcse:searchresults-only></gcse:searchresults-only>
</div>
```

Even though it should bring every search result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to solve it. As Freddie suggested, I was working with a JavaScript rendered webpage, so I needed to use selenium to be able to scrap the web:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser=webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://www.latercera.com/search/?q=camila%20vallejo"
browser.get(url) #navigate to the page
innerHTML = browser.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")
```

With that I'm able to scrap what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I can see the problem. You're looking for a class called 'gsc-wrapper' however when looking at the pages source (different from inspecting) there is no class with that name.

My guess is it's being dynamically generated via JavaScript then injects itself inside the searchresults tags. If you wanted to scrape this you'd need the page to fully render, javascript and all before you would be able to parse.

[Look here for more help.](https://www.quora.com/Can-beautifulsoup-scrape-javascript-rendered-webpages)

Comment: You can use 'class' when it is used as a CSS selector (dictionary notation)

Comment: So there's no way to scrap search results?